# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning using Gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that returns the axes on a figure I created using subplot and gridspecs. It raises a MatplotlibDeprecationWarning and I'd like to understand how I should be doing this. Can anyone help?

```
def get_gridspec():
    fig10 = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
    gs0 = fig10.add_gridspec(1, 2)
    loss_gs = gs0[0].subgridspec(1, 1)
    graphs_gs = gs0[1].subgridspec(2, 1)
    fig10.add_subplot(loss_gs[0])

    for dataset in range(2):
        for irow_metric in range(2):
            for jrow_metric in range(1):
                fig10.add_subplot(graphs_gs[irow_metric, jrow_metric])
    return fig10.axes
```

Raises:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
```

fig10.add_subplot(graphs_gs[irow_metric, jrow_metric])

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is a little awkward.  We are working on a "subfigure" or "subpanel" metaphor that will be less annoying (https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/17375)

OTOH, there is, as of recent matplotlib, a `subplots` method on `gridspec` objects (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpecBase.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpecBase.subplots) that will create the subplots on the figure associated with the gridspec:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig10 = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs0 = fig10.add_gridspec(1, 2)
loss_axs = gs0[0].subgridspec(1, 1).subplots()
graphs_axs = gs0[1].subgridspec(2, 1).subplots()
```

BTW the deprecation warning is because of your outer loop - you are "creating" the axes twice, which is deprecated.

Comment: That is much neater! I couldn't quite follow the whole trace on github, was this merged into the latest versions?

Comment: `GridspecBase.subplots()` is new 3.3.0: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/users/whats_new.html#gridspec-subplots (but so is the deprecation warning ;-)